# how to bind stream_socket_client to an interface in php?

Tags: php, interface, parameters, bind, ip

I have some functions that use stream_socket_client (not curl) in php and I have multiple eth1 eth2 ...etc interfaces with different ips
So i want to use different interfaces when i connect as a client, can I do that?
I can't find no option for that nor in php.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK that's not possible.  Interfaces are abstracted away from PHP; you just get to use them, not choose them.

Edit: let me rephrase that.  If you want to make a system/shell call (eg, `ifconfig -a`) and parse that output, then bind the socket to that particular address, you may have luck... but it seems like iffy business.

Comment: As to how to bind to a particular address, see the [socket context options](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/context.socket.php)

Answer (score 7):

Here is how to add IP interface in stream_socket_client

```
// connect to the internet using the '192.168.0.100' IP
$opts = array(
    'socket' => array(
        'bindto' => '192.168.0.100:0',
    ),
);


// create the context...
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$fp = @stream_socket_client ( $link, $errno, $errstr, 120, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);
```

http://pt.php.net/manual/en/context.socket.php